# Windows account password hash location

Tags: windows, password-hash

I have a machine which I want to find where my password hash is stored.

the `set` command returns details about the account and shows that it is connected to a domain however it doesn't show in `net user`. As well as this on advanced system settings -> User profiles the account shows as type: local and Status: local.

It seems to be a domain user however windows doesn't think it's on a domain.

Because of this searching for hashes has only brought up dead ends. They aren't in the SAM file and they aren't in SECURITY. I also tried password recovery software and the account simply didn't show.

I could see the correct hash through `sekurlsa::LogonPasswords full` - specifically `serkurlsa::msv` with mimikatz but now I would like to know where they are stored.

I know they are cached somewhere as I can login without internet, so I think I'm specifically looking for this file.

A brief search of the command suggests they are in the SAM database but I know they aren't.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: A third chance is that, since Windows 10, you can use a Microsoft account as a replacement for a local login. In that case, the password would be in the Microsoft servers, not in your SAM database.

Comment: If I disconnect from the internet I can still login so there must be a cache somewhere